# How to subset/create a new Pyspark DF based on values from two columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do we filter values for `CID` from the following `df` where the combination of `ID` and `TS` is same.

df =

| ID | CID | TS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C1 | t1 |
| A | C2 | t1 |
| A | C3 | t2 |
| B | C4 | t2 |

Output DF required

| CID |
| --- |
| C1 |
| C2 |

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count for each partition of ID and TS, and filter the rows with a count of greater than or equal to 2.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window 

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'cnt', 
    F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('ID', 'TS'))
).filter('cnt >= 2').select('CID')

df2.show()
+---+
|CID|
+---+
| C1|
| C2|
+---+
```